# One-line function in Dart using “=>”

Tags: dart

One of the many things that I like about Dart is its lack of verbosity.

For example, a one-line function such as the following :

```
  // example 1
String toStr() => (_iValue/_iScale).toStringAsFixed(_iDecimals);
```

However, it would seem to beg the question as to whether there is an equivalent for a one-line function that does not return a value. Eg.

```
// example 2
void deductDbl(double dValue) {
  _iValue -= (dValue * _iScale).toInt();
}
```

While that could be expressed with both “{ and }” on the one line, that is possibly frowned upon. A similar analogy is perhaps a one-line “if statement”, where brackets are not required. I think that most people format that as two lines, because it illustrates the logic better. However, it is still less verbose than using “{}”, although there is still the option of using “{}” if one prefers.

As an alternative to Example 2, I notice that the following appears to work, but may be frowned upon for some reason:

```
   // example 3
deductDbl(double dValue) => _iValue -= (dValue * _iScale).toInt();
```

Is it acceptable to use “Example 3”, or alternatively is there another equivalent to “=>” for a one-line function that does not return a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice is that you shouldn't try to use the `=>` shorthand form for functions that are supposed to have a return type of `void`. Your 3rd example,

```
deductDbl(double dValue) => _iValue -= (dValue * _iScale).toInt();
```

in fact returns an `int`. And to be honest, the difference between this and

```
deductDbl(double dValue) { _iValue -= (dValue * _iScale).toInt(); }
```

is **one** whitespace character. Is it **really** that bad?

Comment: Pretty easy to delete that space! I'd say the real difference is that the second function autoformats to 3 lines, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of taste, so my suggestion is to do whatever feels reasonable to you.

I don't see any problem with writing void functions in shorthand form and I do it often, but it can bite you if you don't know what you are doing.

Your example 3 doesn't behave as you think it does. It is not equivalent to example 2, because in example 3, `deductDbl` returns an `int`.

There is a difference between:

```java
deductDbl1(double dValue) { _iValue -= (dValue * 1).toInt(); } // returns null
```

and

```java
deductDbl2(double dValue) => _iValue -= (dValue * 1).toInt(); // returns int
```

The reason for this is that result of the expression `_iValue -= something` is `_iValue`, so the return type is `int`.

This gives:

```java
var r1 = deductDbl1(x);  // r1 is null!
var r2 = deductDbl2(x);  // r2 is an int equal to _iValue!
```

Comment: On reflection, I think I won't use it because it is probably not a good standard. IE. I personally will only use "=>" where a return value is not wanted. It's a pity there's not an alternative for this case, however I agree it's no big deal. Then again, Dart's quite pedantic about making things marginally better, and that's partly what's so great about it. Hundreds of those marginal minor improvements make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it acceptable to use “Example 3”, or alternatively is there another equivalent to “=>” for a one-line function that does not return a value?

There's no equivalent that doesn't return a value, but I would say it's completely acceptable to use that form. Just remember, if you ever add a type for that method, it should be `int`, not `void` or anything else because that's what it returns.